# Neutral Line current with all breakers off (no load)

Tags: electrical-panel

I have a split-phase system (two live wires, one neutral and a ground line) in my home. When I turn the main breaker off, I still get a 50mA current going from the neutral line and through the earth line. What could be possible causes for this? Is this normal?

This is where I take my measurements:
[image]

Comment: What are those two white boxes on the main lives?  If that is the main panel then neutral and ground should be bonded together.  Split-phase sounds North American, but be nice to confirm your location, different country codes.

Comment: @crip659 I suspect the white boxes are CTs for power monitoring.

Comment: Is the neutral-ground bond in this box? In a meter main? Someplace else? What voltage do you show between neutral and ground with the main breaker off?

Comment: Is this a main panel or a subpanel?  Where is the electric meter from here?

Comment: your measurement is not correct with those fancy current meters

Comment: yes the neutral and gruound are bonded together and voltge between them is 0

Comment: this is the main panel

Comment: the measurement was taken on the red circles with a manual clamp meter (set to 20A Alternate)

Answer (score 8):

A neighbor has a Lost Neutral.   This is where the neutral wire from the utility has broken, and neutral currrent has no way back to the transformer except through their neutral-ground bond, their ground rods, the dirt, your ground rods etc.

Or someone has a 3-wire feed to a subpanel at an outbuilding, and some of the neutral current is pathing through the dirt.

Comment: In the lost neutral scenario you're describing, what's the full circuit that the current is going through? If this were in the United States, then I know that there'd be a path from John Smith's neutral lead of his transformer, through his transformer to a hot lead, through the hot busbar in the breaker panel, through an appliance, into the neutral bar, through the bond to the ground bar, into the ground rod, through the ground, into _my_ ground rod, through the bond to the neutral bar, and up to the neutral lead of my transformer...

Comment: But that's not a complete circuit, since the neutral lead of John Smith's transformer isn't connected to the neutral lead of my transformer, and there's no second path for the current to take.

Comment: Of course, I don't know what country this actually is, so maybe all of what I just said is inapplicable here.

Comment: I would guess Mexico given the US-style panel and wiring w/labeling in spanish.  A majority of Mexico's electrical distribution mirrors the US, although you'll sometimes find european-style distrubution panels attached to US-style split phase 240V transmission.

Comment: @Tanner ah, you're presuming each house has its own transformer and thus isolation between services.  No, typically many houses are served by 1 transformer.

Comment: @Harper-ReinstateMonica Ah! I didn't know that. Thanks for clearing that up for me!